# C# Starting Powershell ps1 File in batch with Process.Start()

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file

I have a problem with starting a powershell inside a batch script with C#:

I wan't to replace the EnvironmentVariable "CLIENTNAME"for the Process so i did it like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
pi.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("test.bat");
pi.UseShellExecute = false;
pi.EnvironmentVariables["clientname"] = clientname;
Process.Start(pi);
```

My "test.bat" looks like this:

```
powershell %logonserver%\netlogon\test.ps1
pause
```

The result is that I get this exception:

```
Windows PowerShell terminated with the following error:
Invalid Signature. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090006)
```

If I start the test.bat with doubleclick everything works fine...
Why?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you launch a *batch* file to run a PowerShell script? Why don’t you just run PowerShell directly?

Comment: If i run Powershell directly i can't see the output if a error occurs. But the Problem if starting directly stays the same... Don't know why

Comment: Can you launch a .bat file if `UseShellExecute = false`? (A .bat file is a text file processed by cmd.exe.) I would try `UseShellExecute = true`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: The problem is that if I want to use `pi.EnvironmentVariables["clientname"] = clientname;` I can't use ShellExecute.

Answer (score 0):

now I have the answer to my question:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("clientname", clientname);
ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
pi.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("test.bat");
pi.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(pi);
```